# Use of mögen vs gern

Tags: modal-verb, semantics

From my understanding, the general meaning of the word *mögen* is *to like*. And the addition of the word *gern* in a sentence such as *Ich trinke Kaffee gern* means that you like to drink coffee.

But is there any semantic difference between saying *Ich mag Kaffee zu trinken* and *Ich trinke Kaffee gern*?

It seems like they both generally translate to *I like to drink coffee*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

»Mögen« is a verb:

> Ich mag Kaffee.
>   I like coffee.
>
> Ich mag es, Kaffee zu trinken.
>   I like to drink coffee.

But »gern« is an adverb:

> Ich trinke gerne Kaffee
>   Verbatim: I gladly drink coffee.
>   (same pattern as in: *I often drink coffee* = *Ich trinke oft Kaffee*)

But you don't have an adverb in english that means the same like the german adverb »gern« So you have to build the sentence in a different way:

> I like to drink coffee.

But if you translate this verbatim into German, then you get this:

> Ich mag es, Kaffee zu trinken.

Comment: likely=wahrscheinlich, likewise=ebenso

Comment: @CarstenS: yes, you are right. I just tried to write an English word, that is an adverb and might be understood as an English version of the German adverb »gern«. I know that there is no such word, and whatever I would write, would be wrong. That is why I wrote the sentence *But you don't have an adverb in english that means the same like the german adverb »gern«*.

Comment: The adverb *gladly* is very close to a direct translation of *gern* - certainly in the sentence *Ich trinke gerne Kaffee* one would naturally translate it as "I gladly drink coffee"/"I drink coffee gladly".

Comment: @DavidHall: Thank you. I corrected it in my answer